# Is this line of Perl meaningless? s/^(\d+)\b/$1/sg

Tags: regex, perl

Does this line of Perl really do anything?

```
$variable =~ s/^(\d+)\b/$1/sg;
```

The only thing I can think of is that `$1` or `$&` might be re-used, but it is immediately followed by.

```
$variable =~ s/\D//sg;
```

With these two lines together, is the first line meaningless and removable? It seems like it would be, but I have seen it multiple times in this old program, and wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$variable =~ s/^(\d+)\b/$1/sg;
```

- The anchor `^` at the beginning makes the `/g` modifier useless.
- The lack of the wildcard character `.` in the string makes the `/s` modifier useless, since it serves to make `.` also match newline.
- Since `\b` and `^` are zero-width assertions, and the only things outside the capture group, this substitution will not change the variable at all.

The only thing this regex does is capture the digits into `$1`, if they are found.

The subsequent regex

```
$variable =~ s/\D//sg;
```

Will remove all non-digits, making the variable just one long number. If one wanted to separate the first part (matched by the first regex), the only way to do so would be by accessing `$1` from the first regex.

However, the first regex in that case would be better written simply:

```
$variable =~ /^(\d+)\b/;
```

And if the capture is supposed to be used:

```
my ($num) = $variable =~ /^(\d+)\b/;
```

Answer (score 6):

Is "taint mode" in use?  (Script is invoked with -T option.)

Maybe it's used to sanitize (i.e. untaint) user input.

Comment: No, not used, but very interesting! I never knew about this.